# Wordpress full post showing

Tags: wordpress

When I am posting something on wordpress, it is showing the full post. I want to hide the full post and show some lines. So user an click on the read more link the the full post will be shown. plz any Idea or plugin .

my Site: http://mlmpublicnews.com/

Comment: use substr() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [automatic read more generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-read-more-generator/).  It will hide everything after the first image or first paragraph until the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

See these with some examples. May get handy..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Read-More-to-Wordpress

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use the_excerpt() instead of the_content()

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
         the_excerpt();
     endwhile;
?>
```

[Read More](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)